# Query key condition not supported in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm attempting to set up my DynamoDB table so I can query the data via a rest API. My table has a partition key (id) which is a randomly generated ID, a sort key (name) and a List of strings (domain).

I have also set up a global secondary index for the "name" field.

I'm attempting to write a lambda that will search for items using both the name and possible search the domain array also. Is this possible? If so how do I set up the table as I'm currently getting this error:

```
Query key condition not supported
```

Here is my Lambda query code:

```js
async function query(tableName, searchTerm) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      IndexName: "nameIndex",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#name": "name",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":topic": { S: searchTerm },
      },
      KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(#name, :topic)",
      TableName: tableName,
    };

    ddb.query(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Items);
        resolve(data.Items);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: If by 'uniquely-generated ID', you mean that every item has a unique `id` value (such as a UUID), then I don't think it makes sense to have `name` as SK. It should just be a regular attribute. Or are there multiple items with the same `id` value?

Comment: FYI no need to create your own promises. You can use `const data = await ddb.query(params).promise();`

Comment: @jarmod Yeah the IDs are random; I'm just looking for a way to query the names for each row. I thought the name had to be an index to do so. Also thanks for the heads up on the promise situation.

Comment: GSI on name would be sufficient. The only value in having an SK is when you have a PK that can actually be used to group values e.g. PK=country, SK=town or PK=user, SK=game.

Answer (score 2):

A PK must be provided as a value. You can't do expressions like begins with on a PK.

Here are a lot of example programs doing queries with Node:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithQueries

Comment: In their query examples, the ID is always known (KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :id and begins_with(#dt, :dt)'). In my case it is not. How can I just search on the name field without knowing the id value?

Comment: If name is a string and your GSI has it setup as the PK then you don’t need the id when querying the GSI.

Comment: If name is a list of strings, you can’t make a list a PK.